# mysql query to find contiguous datetime records with start and stop fields

Tags: mysql

In the transportation industry, regulations limit hours-of-service.

I have a mysql database that includes a table with an auto_increment field called `Task_ID`, an integer field with a foreign key called `User_ID`, and two datetime fields, `Start_DT`, and `End_DT`.

Table:

```
 Task_ID | User_ID | Start_DT | End_DT
```

An employee's shift can include several tasks, each creating a record.

I already have a query that identifies the most recent endtime, by employee, (`User_ID`). (The html user interface prevents data entry where the starttime would be later than the endtime.).

I need to create a query that would return all the records contiguous to the most recent endtime (by employee). In other words, all the records in which the starttime of the current record is equal to the end time of the previous record (by employee). The number of tasks (records) in the series varies.

Should I nest enough subqueries to be confident that no contiguous series of tasks will exceed that in number of tasks, or is there a way to look for a gap and return all records later than the gap?

There's lots of advice for finding gaps in a single field, but my searching hasn't found much appropriate to this question.

(Responding to Strawberry's comments below:)

1)

```
CREATE TABLE `hoursofservice` (
    `Task_ID` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `User_ID` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `Location` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Task` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Start_DT` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `End_DT` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Comment_1` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Comment_2` VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Bad_Data` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`Task_ID`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `Task_ID` (`Task_ID`),
    INDEX `FK_hoursofservice_employee_id` (`User_ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_hoursofservice_employee_id` FOREIGN KEY (`User_ID`) REFERENCES `employee_id` (`User_ID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

and ...

```
INSERT INTO hoursofservice (User_ID, Location, Task, Start_DT, End_DT, Comment_1, Comment_2)
SELECT User_ID, Location, Task, Start_DT, End_DT, Comment_1, Comment_2 FROM read_text_file;
```

2) Result set would be records selected from the table such that the start time from the most recent record would equal the end time from the previous, and likewise until there was no record that met the condition. (These would be ordered by User_ID.)

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Thanks for the coaching. I'm a novice to the protocol.

Comment: Don't tell us. Show us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work for you:

```
SELECT islands.[all relevant fields from "theTable"]
FROM (
    SELECT [all relevant fields from "theTable"]
        , @i := CASE
             WHEN @prevUserId <> User_ID THEN 1 -- Reset "island" counter for each user
             WHEN @prevStart <> End_DT THEN @i + 1 -- Increment "island" counter when gaps found
             ELSE @i -- Do not change "island" counter
             END AS island
        , @prevStart := Start_DT -- Remember this Start_DT value for the next row
        , @prevUserId := User_ID -- Remember this User_ID value for the next row
    FROM (
        SELECT t.*
        FROM theTable AS t
        WHERE End_DT < [known or "ceiling" End_DT]
           AND [limiting condition (for speed), 
                something like Start_DT > [ceiling] - INTERVAL 3 DAY
               ]
        ORDER BY User_ID, End_DT DESC
    ) AS candidates -- Insures rows are in appropriate order for use with session variables.
                    -- Allows us to treat the inclosing query somewhat like a loop.
    , (SELECT @i := 0
             , @prevStart := '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
             , @prevUserId := -1
      ) AS init -- Initializing session variables; 
                -- can actually be done in preceeding SET statements 
                -- if the connection is preserved between the SETs and the query.
    ORDER BY User_ID, Start_DT
) AS islands -- Data from "theTable" should now have appropriate "islands" calculated
WHERE islands.island = 1 -- Only keep the first "island" for each user
ORDER BY islands.User_ID, islands.Start_DT
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer, DoubleU-ear-dough. The boss put me on something else, so I haven't had a chance to try your solution until today. The mysql version I get to use is 5.3.3. It didn't like the table alias "t", but it runs if the "t"s are replaced with the table name. Unfortunately, it returns the most recent record, not the first gap between contiguous records. Any ideas?

Comment: Without seeing the query you tried, my first guess would be you did not group by every field in "theTable"...(oh, and the reason it probably didn't like the `t` was probably because I should not have shown it used in the outer query that way). The `t.*` on line 1 was meant to indicate all fields from "theTable", not literally `t.*`. I'll make an edit, because now that I think about it, I don't usually use GROUP BY or HAVINGs when doing this so it probably needs another layer of quering.

Comment: Do the SELECT statements in lines 3 and 12 use the alias set out in line 13? I've tried using t.[fieldname], [fieldname] as well as [tablename].[fieldname], [fieldname], and I've tried surrounding these individually with backticks. All variations return "SQL Error (1054) Unknown Column t.[fieldname] in field list." Any ideas?

Comment: @dirk The alias `t` is only valid within the `candidates` subquery; outside of it use `candidates.[fieldname]`; and outside the `islands` subquery use `islands.[fieldname]`. _If there are no ambiguities, just specifying the field names should be enough._  ...and just to make absolutely sure, you should not be actually using the `[` and `]` symbol to delimit fields in MySQL; I use them in the answer to indicate "fill in the blank".

Comment: You might be a little uueerd, but you're also quite generous. The query ran as presented. (I did understand the square brackets meant "fill in the blank"). As this is my first post on this forum, could you describe how I might add to your "reputation" as a reflection of how much I appreciate your help? Thank you, muchly.